# QProcess - как получить вывод процесса до его завершения?

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть приложение на Qt, включающее код такого вида :

```
QProcess proc;
...
proc.setProgramm("Python34\\python");
proc.setArguments(QStringList{"hello.py"});
proc.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
connect(&proc, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, []() {
  QString output = QString(proc.readAllStandardOutput());
  ...
});
proc.start();
```

Но `readyReadStandardOutput` отлавливается только после завершения процесса. В моём случае - требуется проделать определённые действия до завершения (по наличию в выводе определённого текста).

Как это реализовать?

upd. Более подробный код имеет вид :

```
class Window: public QMainWindow {
...
  private:
    QVector<QProcess*> processes;
    void createProcesses();
    void prepareProcess(QProcess* proc);
}

void MainWindow::createProcesses() {
  for(int i=0;...) {
    processes.append(new QProcess());
    prepareProcess(&processes[processes.size()-1]);
  }
}

void MainWindow::prepareProcess(QProcess* proc) {
  proc->setProgramm("Python34\\python");
  proc->setArguments(QStringList{"hello.py"});
  proc->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
  connect(&proc, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, []() {
    QString output = QString(proc->readAllStandardOutput());
    ...
  });
  proc->start();
}
```

UPD. А в Qt ли вообще дело? Обнаружил следующее.
При запуске, например `ping /t ya.ru` результат выводится. Но, с применением например, следующего питоноскрипта - нет

```
import time
while True:
  print("Hello")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было не в приложении на Qt, а в буферизации вывода python-ом (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Лечится запуском с опцией -u

Answer (score 3):

В справке по обозначенному сигналу говорится, что последний будет отправляться по мере поступления новых данных. То есть не по завершению процесса, а именно во время работы процесса.

Метод `QProcess::start()` является асинхронным. Объект `QProcess` у Вас создаётся в стеке. В связи с этим, возможно, что проблема заключается в несвоевременном уничтожении объекта, либо в отсутствии вызова цикла событий, что в свою очередь ведёт к помещению отправленного сигнала в очередь. Соответственно, и получается, что сигнал доходит постфактум, а не тогда, когда его вызвали.

Создавайте объект `QProcess` в куче (через `new`), либо после вызова метода `QProcess::start()` при помощи `QEventLoop` активируйте локальный цикл событий. Ну или, как ещё один вариант, воспользуйтесь блокирующим ожиданием: `QProcess::waitForReadyRead()`.

Comment: Пересмотрел ещё раз имеющийся на деле код - таки на самом деле в куче, хотя тут не показал.`waitForReadyRead` применить возможности нет.

Comment: @user3476487 , может потому, что квадратные скобки пустые. По идее для лямбды нужно указать захват указателя `proc`.

Comment: Ну, сейчас после пары перемен вообще творится чёрти что - бесконечный питоновый hello не читает, а вот ping /t - хавает на ура...